# How to do padding left in bootstrap5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, bootstrap-modal

In bootstrap4 we've used pl-5 for padding left, in bootstrap5 it is not working.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-9 p-3 pl-5"> in bootstrap5 this code is not working
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According [to the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/) the class names are `ps-` or `pe-` ... meaning start / end rather than left or right.

The reason is, that if you switch from RTL to LTR site your padding would still be applied from the correct side.

```
<div class="ps-2">I have a padding left on LTR and a padding right on RTL languages</div>
```

Comment: great thanks, this work for me 

Answer (score 7):

In bootstrap-5 pl and pr is replaced ps and pe respectively.

`

```
  <div className="col-md-4 pt-5 ps-3" style={colBorder}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit 


                         amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, sed!</div>


  <div className="col-md-4 pb-5 pe-5" style={colBorder2}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit 


                         amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, sed!</div>


</div>
```

`